# Strange bug with \frac and \text in comments

Tags: bug, mathjax, comment

In a recent comment, I used the `\text{}` command inside a `\frac{}{}` command several times, and the comment was broken. Trimming it down several times to try to produce a minimal example, I found quite odd behavior.

The following input breaks in a comment:

```
$\frac{\text{aaaaa}}{\text{aaaaa}}=\left(\frac{\text{aaaaa}}{\text{aaaaa}}\right)$
```

producing

[image]

Remove **any** of the `a`'s, or the `=`, and the above comment displays correctly. The comment also displays correctly if one removes the `\left` and `\right` commands.

If you write the same comment, except with `$$`'s around the expression instead of just `$`'s, the threshold goes down by one character; remove any **two** of the `a`'s, or an `a` and the `=`, and the comment displays correctly, otherwise it is broken.

The original example, and all of the versions described above, display correctly when put in the answer field.

Now, I think that perhaps there's something to be said for the argument "you shouldn't be using `\text{}` so much anyway, or at least not inside `\frac{}{}`", but I don't know what else this bug might affect, so I am reporting it.

I'm using Chrome 19.0.1084.52 on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: My guess is that this is something to do with the automatic linebreaks. In the following comment I have added a space after the `=` symbol:

Comment: $\frac{\text{aaaaa}}{\text{aaaaa}}= \left(\frac{\text{aaaaa}}{\text{aaaaa}}\right)$

Comment: This seems related to [this issue](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3968/5363) observed by joriki and the workaround explained by robjohn in an answer there works: insert some blanks in the endless worm of TeX (e.g. around the equality sign) and it works: $\frac{\text{aaaaa}}{\text{aaaaa}} = \left(\frac{\text{aaaaa}}{\text{aaaaa}}\right)$. @Asaf: yep.

Comment: @t.b.: You should post that as an answer. I would do that myself, but I have a meeting with the sandman, Morpheus and other mythological creatures related to the realm of sleep...

Comment: It appears that some of the MathJax developers read this forum, but note that the project does [accept bug reports](http://www.mathjax.org/resources/faqs/#problem-report).